# Statement level trigger

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have a trigger for a table called `A_TAB` which as only one column `A` of character type. and I have a another table `DUP_A` which has same column as `TAB_A`.Trigger for `A_TAB` as follows

```
create or replace trigger A_trig
    before insert on A_TAB 
    for each row
declare
    num1 varchar2(50):= null;
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
    select Wm_Concat(a) into  num1 from DUP_A;
    if num1 is null 
    then
      num1:=:new.a;
    else
      num1:=num1||','||:new.a;
    end if;
    insert into DUP_A values(num1);  
    delete from DUP_A where rowid<>(select max(rowid) from DUP_A);
commit;
end;
```

Here I'm concatenating all the values that in newly inserted and inserting it to a single column of `DUP_A`.

It's working fine but, I need `statement level trigger` with same functionality

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Removing "for each row" clause will change row level trigger to statement level trigger .But PL/SQL runtime engine creates and populates
two data structures(:new and :old) that functions much like records only When a row-level trigger is fired

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference data (`:new` and `:old`) in a statement level trigger.